# problem to handle cart count in every activity. and count is destroy when back to another activity

Tags: android

> ActivityProductList.java

```
public class ActivityProductList extends BaseActivity {}
```

> Adapter class

```
 ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.add(new HoldMyCart(Subproductname, Subproductamount, product_image, qty, product_type_id));
```

((BaseActivity) context).doincreament();

**Its working fine and count is increasing after addition of the arraylist but in MainActivity Cart is not increasing as well as when back to Another Acidity and again come to this activity the arraylist.size() is > 0 but the count is again 0**

Comment: add your counter as static and access every where you want.

Comment: Or you can save it in SharedPreference.

Comment: if (ActivityProductList.mNotifCount!=0){
            notifCount.setText(ActivityProductList.mNotifCount);
        }else {
            notifCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

getting Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.argosupplier.Activity.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:300)

Comment: #chirag Savsani how ? Actually I have tried once

Answer (score 0):

i think in your case shared preference would be easy to use....
to add some data to your shared preference you can use

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("GiveName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("key_one", "vaue1");
editor.putString("key_two", "vaue2");
editor.putString("key_three", "vaue3");
editor.putBoolean("key_four", true);
editor.apply();
```

Now to retrieve the data from your shared preferences you can use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("GiveName", MODE_PRIVATE);
String keyOne = prefs.getString("key_one", "some_default_value");
Boolean keyFour = prefs.getBoolean("key_four", false);
```

you can get the data from your shared preferences at the start of your activity and show the cart count accordingly. Hope this helps

Comment: I have done the same thing as well through Shared pref but it not getting the solution.

Comment: if the count shows on doincreament() function....then using shared pref should solve the issue....may be a minor issue....

Answer (score 0):

You simply accumulate all your repeated action inside a `BaseActivity` like below:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static int mNotifCount = 0;
    TextView notifCount;

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
        View count = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart).getActionView();
        notifCount = (TextView) count.findViewById(R.id.txt_count_cartItem);

        //Set this here
        notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
    }

    public void doincreament() {
        mNotifCount++;
        notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
    }
}
```

And then `extends` this `BaseActivity` on those activities that needs these action. For example `ActivityProductList`.

```
public class ActivityProductList extends BaseActivity {

}
```

Comment: Sorry accidentally I delete your question. But you can do like this: ``public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener``

Comment: Just use `BaseActivity` instead of  `AppCompatActivity` wherever you need the Cart

Comment: Did the same things but problem is count is not increasing in everyactivity as well as when finish that activity its remains zero again where my arralist.size() is more that 0. but yea when adding data it increasing from remaining count

Comment: Could you please post your updated code?  Also try making `static int mNotifCount = 0;` to static

Comment: Base Activity is same as you have done. only i have made mNotifCount as static.

and when adding data just call ((BaseActivity) context).doincreament();

Comment: After making static what's the result?

Comment: Same Activity  cart value is increasing but when going to other activity its shows zero means only one data is increasing

Comment: Check my updated answer. Also set the value inside `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Actually I thing the problem is when i am back from that layout that count is again 0. I am sure about it because after back to the previous activity and then go to again the same activity the count is 0 and starts from 1 again

Comment: can i store that arraylist.size() like mNotifCount. bcs arraylist.size()>0 but mNotifCount is zero after layout change

Comment: sure. you can do that. Or you can sets the value like this `mNotifCount = arraylist.size()'

Comment: It's working fine to me. Don't know why not in your side. do you reset the count from anywhere?

Comment: First where I have Initialized  mNotifCount  = 0 now I have Initialized   that  static  int mNotifCount = ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.size();

 static  int mNotifCount;

Everywhere it works now but in the MainActivity cart is not updated still in the both cases as